# Is it ok for a viewmodel function to have a parameter that receives a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I have a fragment for user input and a viewmodel to handle the validation and IO. Upon insertion of the info I have the UI navigate to a 'success' dialog. Right now this navigation happens from the viewmodel's
insert method using a reference to the fragment. It all seems to work but then I remembered a viewmodel shouldn't hold a reference to a fragment or activity. My question is does that apply to a local parameter for a function of the viewmodel? Will it somehow hold on to that reference?

ViewModel code

```
suspend fun insertNewCustomer(name: String?,address: String?, city: String?, state: String?,
                      phoneNumber: String?, emailAddress: String?, frag: ManualAddCustomerFrag
 ){
    if (    (validateName(name)
            && validateAddress(address)
            && validateCity(city)
            && validateState()
            && validateServiceDays())
        && isAddressTaken(address) == false

    ){

        val customer = CustomerEntity(address!!,name,city,state,phoneNumber, emailAddress)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            customerRepo.insertCustomer(customer)

            val days = convertSelectedDaysToStrings()
            for (i in days.indices){
                val serviceDay = ServiceDayEntity(0,customer.address,days[i])
                customerRepo.addServiceDay(serviceDay)

            }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                val dialogFragment = SuccessfullyAddedDialog()
                val action = ManualAddCustomerFragDirections.
                actionManualAddCustomerFragToSuccessfullyAddedDialog()
                frag.findNavController().navigate(action)
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of showing / navigating to the dialog from ViewModel, just pass this info to the Activity or Fragment and handle it from the there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewModel and Fragment should be separated and one should never pass a Fragment as a parameter to a ViewModel. If you want to trigger a Fragment action by a ViewModel, you should use an Observer in the Fragment. I'll post some snippets of my own code to explain what I mean. It should be noted that I'm using an Activity here instead of a Fragment, but the concept remains the same.

In the ViewModel I created these variables:

```
val closeInCall: LiveData<EmptyEvent>
    get() = _closeInCall

private val _closeInCall = MutableLiveData<EmptyEvent>()
```

When a certain method in the ViewModel gets triggered, this happens:

```
_closeInCall.postValue(EmptyEvent())
```

In my Activity I observe `closeInCall` like this:

```
viewModel.closeInCall.observe(this, EventObserver {
    // Do stuff
})
```

The EmptyEvent and EventObserver that I am using are MVVM helper classes I like to use when I don't need to receive any values in the Fragment/Activity, you don't necessarily have to use them.

EmptyEvent:

```
/**
 * An [Event] without content.
 */
class EmptyEvent : Event<Unit>(Unit)
```

EventObserver:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer

/**
 * An [Observer] for [Event]s, simplifying the pattern of checking if 
the [Event]'s content has
 * already been handled.
 *
 * [onEventUnhandledContent] is *only* called if the [Event]'s 
contents has not been handled.
 */
internal class EventObserver<T>(
    private val onEventUnhandledContent: (T) -> Unit
) : Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>?) {
        event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { value ->
            onEventUnhandledContent(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `lambda` function to handle `callback` in `Activity/Fragment` from `ViewModel`. Like below:

```
    fun insertNewCustomer(name: String?,address: String?, city: String?, state: String?,
                                  phoneNumber: String?, emailAddress: String?, callBack: () -> Unit
    ){
        if (    (validateName(name)
                    && validateAddress(address)
                    && validateCity(city)
                    && validateState()
                    && validateServiceDays())
            && isAddressTaken(address) == false

        ){

            val customer = CustomerEntity(address!!,name,city,state,phoneNumber, emailAddress)
            viewModelScope.launch {
                customerRepo.insertCustomer(customer)

                val days = convertSelectedDaysToStrings()
                for (i in days.indices){
                    val serviceDay = ServiceDayEntity(0,customer.address,days[i])
                    customerRepo.addServiceDay(serviceDay)

                }
                callBack()
               /* withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    val dialogFragment = SuccessfullyAddedDialog()
                    val action = ManualAddCustomerFragDirections.
                    actionManualAddCustomerFragToSuccessfullyAddedDialog()
                    frag.findNavController().navigate(action)
                }*/

            }
        }
    }
```

Add call above method from `Activity/Fragment` as below:

```
        lifecycleScope.launch {
        yourViewModel.insertNewCustomer("name","address","city","state","phone","email"){
            val dialogFragment = SuccessfullyAddedDialog()
            val action = ManualAddCustomerFragDirections.
            actionManualAddCustomerFragToSuccessfullyAddedDialog()
            
            // If you are using binding, then use binding.root where binding is an instance variable instantiated in onCreateView() of Fragment
            binding.root.findNavController().navigate(action)
            // Or else you can get NavController from View
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. insertNewCustomer is definitely something which needs to happen in the ViewModel. The Activity/Fragment should only contain code to control the UI, the ViewModel should handle the logic. Or did you mean viewModel.insertNewCustomer?

Comment: Yes, it must be viewModel.insertNewCustomer.